# Which number has more trailing zeros in binary representation

Tags: java, binary

Given two numbers, A and B, I am wondering what the most efficient way to determine which of them has more trailing zeros (in binary representation) using Java would be.

I could determine the number of trailing zeros for both of them individually, but I don't know if this is the best approach or if there is some binary magic that could do it better.

**Note**: the numbers can be very large, I need to use `BigInteger`.

Comment: [`Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros%28int%29)

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I am using `BigInteger` since these can be very large numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html), you can use [`BigInteger#getLowestSetBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#getLowestSetBit()) to determine the number of zero bits to the right of the rightmost one bit.

```
System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(32).getLowestSetBit());
```

Output:

```
5
```

---

Note: this method returns `-1` if the number contains no one bits (i.e. `0`).

Comment: I didn't know that this method existed, great!